# Rotate text inside table and align it to the centre of combined rows

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, rotating

I would like to rotate text inside a table and align to the centre as shown. The next column has several other rows which are combined in the "standards" row. Something similar to the first picture(aligning with the vertical line) and not the second. I would appreciate suggestions on the best way to do this. Thanks

[image] [image]

Comment: i've removed the `[align]` tag because that is for a very particular multi-line math display environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\rotatebox` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|}
\hline\\
\hline
& standards\\
\rotatebox{90}{standards }&\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I would also like to align it to the centre of the column

Answer (score 3):

If you want to center the column vertically, you should use the `m{...}` option from `array` package.

This would affect the alignment of all the cells of the column, if you need something different, please add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/101651).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|m{1em}|c|}
        \hline
        & \\
        \hline
        \rotatebox{90}{standards }& \makecell{standards \\ just\\ to \\ show \\ that \\ the \\ previous \\ it's centered }\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]